# Return statement inside for loop(algorithm scripting)

Tags: javascript

I am doing an algorithm, the function takes 2 arguments,an array and another object. If one of the values in the objects in the array matches one value of the second arguments then i'm required to return that array object.
my  return statement is not working

```
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
    let r = Object.values(source);

    console.log(r);
    for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
        console.log(Object.values(collection[i]));

        if (Object.values(collection[i]) == r) {
            return Object.values(collection[i])
        }
    }
}
```

sample test:

```
whatIsInAName([{ first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }, { first: "Mercutio", last: null }, { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }], { last: "Capulet" }));
```

The return statement does not work so i can't even tell if my  logic is wrong or write

Comment: You're comparing references in memory rather than the keys and values between both objects.

Comment: `Object.values(collection[i]) == r` will return `false` because arrays can't be compared like this.

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing references in memory rather than the keys and values between both objects.

You can use the function `every` as an approach in order to compare the keys and values.

*This is assuming the values are not objects (key-value pairs) nor arrays.*

```
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
    for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
        if (Object.entries(collection[i]).every(([key, value]) => source[key] === value)) {
            return Object.values(collection[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use another loop to iterate over *'r'* and use indexOf/includes to check if it exists in the current iteration of *collection*

```
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
    let r = Object.values(source);

    console.log(r);
    for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
        console.log(Object.values(collection[i]));
        for (let j = 0; j < r.length; j++) {
            if (Object.values(collection[i]).indexOf(r[j]) != -1) {
                return Object.values(collection[i])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you are trying to achieve.

```
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
    let r = Object.values(source);

        for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) { 

          if (collection[i].last == source.last) {

              return Object.values(collection[i])
          }
        }

}
var data = whatIsInAName([{ first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }, { first: "Mercutio", last: null }, { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }], { last: "Capulet" });

console.log(data);
```